# Is it possible to change the sorl lib generated thumbnails to any other path?

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

by default sorl saves thumbnails inside images folder. it creates cache folder inside images folder by default. how can i change this to any path ?

Comment: You should try and go back and accept more answers to your previous questions. It will give people more incentive to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the paths within the cache folder as they directly relate to how the thumbnail is referenced in the key/value store backend. [You can see where these paths and filenames are generated in the github source.](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/base.py#L92)

You **can** change where the actual cache folder is located though by setting the [`THUMBNAIL_PREFIX` setting](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/conf/defaults.py#L48) (which will be created under your `MEDIA_ROOT` - i.e. `/media/cache/`)